# using lambda function to erase copies of same value in std::vector

Tags: c++, unique, stdvector, erase

I have a sorted std::vector. I want to erase copies of the same values inside the vector according to vec.i where i is an int. I used a lambda function for sorting but don't know how to use it for `unique` function.

```
sort( vec.begin(), vec.end(), [] (Vector const &v1, Vector const &v2) {return (v1.i < v2.i);} );
// how to use lambda function for the following?
vec.erase( unique( vec.begin(), vec.end() ), vec.end() );
```

Answer (score 4):

The only reason you would want to use a lambda with `std::unique()` is if the regular equality operator for your datatype wasn't sufficient. If `v1 == v2` returns `true` then you can just do:

```
auto it = std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end());
vec.erase(it, vec.end());
```

If you need more control over the comparison then a lambda can be used as so:

```
auto it = std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2) {
  // comparison function that returns true or false
  return v1.i == v2.i;
});
vec.erase(it, vec.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
auto same_i = [](Vector const& v1, Vector const& v2) { return v1.i == v2.i; };
vec.erase(unique(vec.begin(), vec.end(), same_i), vec.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::unique` can take a predicate, but it takes 3 arguments when you use it:

```
vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const Vector& v1, const Vector& v2) { return v1.i == v2.i; }), vec.end());
```